# Javascript: Array of objects, changing value in each object asynchronously

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, cloudinary

So, I know this has been asked before and I have tried other answers like `.map`, `(function(post){ async })(value)`, and I am still stuck...

so, I have an array of objects and a for loop:

```
var postsData = [{thumbnail: www.website.com/image.jpg}, {thumbnail: www.website.com/image.jpg}, {thumbnail... etc}];

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let thumbnail = postsData[i].thumbnail;
  Cloudinary.uploader.upload(thumbnail, function(result){
    // not sure what to do here
    // result comes back as an object, and I want to change each thumbnail in
    // the postsData array to be result.public_id
  }, {transformation:[{}]});
} // go through all the items in the array

// do something with "updated" postsData array
```

An example would really help, as obviously, getting the values changed involves some async functions.

Comment: your `postsData` is invalid - perhaps that's a starting point (the values should be strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `"thumbnail"` property of object in array to `result.public_id`. Create a function where expected parameter is current object within `postsData` array, set `"thumbnail"` property of object by passing function reference to `upload` function, passing current object of array `prop` object utilizing `Function.prototype.bind()`

```
var len = postsData.length;
var n = 0;

function handleData(result, prop) {
  prop["thumbnail"] = result_public.id;
  if (++n === len) complete(postsData);
}

function complete(data) {
  console.log(data, postsData);
}

for (let prop of postsData) {
  Cloudinary.uploader.upload(
    thumbnail
    , handleData.bind(null, prop)
    , {transformation:[{}]}
  );
}
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/SSyUG03pyAwXMVpHdGnc?p=preview

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately, when I called postsData after the for, the thumbnails were all the same still...

Comment: _"Tried that, but unfortunately, when I called postsData after the for, the thumbnails were all the same still"_ When did you log `postsData` at `console`? `Cloudinary.uploader.upload` callback function sets `result` asynchronously, yes? `let thumbnail = postsData.thumbnail;` is probably needed before `Cloudinary.uploader.upload()` call as `thumbnail` is `undefined` at `javascript` at Answer.

Comment: So, I have tried just using the for-prop-loop, where `let thumbnail = prop.thumbnail;` then I call `console.log(postsData);` after and outside the for-prop-loop, your example wasn't using the for (i++) loop, so I removed that... but I still end up with the same postsData array.

Comment: @Daltron You can define a named function, use `Function.prototype.bind()` to pass `prop` as first parameter, within function, set `this["thumbnail"] = result.public_id`; for example `var n = 0, len = postsData.length; function  handleData(result) {
    this["thumbnail"] = result.public_id;
    ++n; 
    if (n === len) complete(postsData);
  }; Cloudinary.uploader.upload(thumbnail, handleData.bind(prop), {transformation:[{}]})`, see http://plnkr.co/edit/SSyUG03pyAwXMVpHdGnc?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising (pun intended), I'm going to go watch 'Mars Attacks', but I will try your solution tomorrow morning and post results.

Comment: As it turns out, your updated solution worked with some minor tweaking. I had to change `handleData.bind(null, prop)` to `function(result) { handleData(result, prop); }`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to loop through an array and do async function on each of its element. What I would do is to use Promise.js (see [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)). So the code would look something like this:

```
// create an array for the promises
const PromiseArr = [];
postsData.map(d => {
  PromiseArr.push(
    // do async actions and push them to array
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Cloudinary.uploader.upload(thumbnail,(result) => {
         // return the result
         resolve(result);
       });
    })
  );
})
// do all async actions and store the result in result array
const result = PromiseArr.all();
```